# window.location is acting weird. It does not redirect to specified path

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess

I have this simple ajax call to fire an API to validate login credentials.

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + "agent/login",
        type: 'post',
        data: {login: $('#login').val(), password: $('#password').val()},
        success: function (results) {
           if(results.status === 0){
               window.location = baseURL + "agent/dashboard";
           }
           else{
               alert(results.message);
           }
        },
        error: function(data) {
           alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Now the full target URL is `localhost/app/agent/login`. The `baseURL = http://localhost/app/`.

I am receiving the request at the server. But when I respond back the `window.location` wont redirect me to `localhost/app/agent/dashboard` rather it's redirecting to `http://localhost/app/agent/localhost/app/agent/login`

I dont understand why this is happening. Here's my `.htaccess` if it helps

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.4 on XAMPP

Comment: Are you certain `baseURL === 'http://localhost/app/'`? Have you tried just logging out `baseURL` to confirm what it is?

Comment: What happens if you just try typing the URL `http://localhost/app/agent/dashboard` into the address bar?

Comment: Despite of all the answers, it your comment that solved the problem. Turns out there was a bad redirect at `dashboard`. Such simplea nd fundamental debugging practices really help sometimes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location` is an object you should not assign url to it.

For more information go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

> The Window.location read-only property returns a Location object with
>   information about the current location of the document.

what you should do is `window.location.href = your_url`

(simulates click on a link in page with the url.)

or use `window.location.replace(your_url)` to redirect to the url.

Answer (score 1):

use your window.location like this way

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `baseURL` is being interpreted as a relative URL instead of an absolute URL.  You should either specify the full URL `http://localhost/app/agent/login` OR truncate `baseURL` to `/app/agent/login`